# How vuejs knows the depenedencies of computed property for caching?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this Vue.js code:

```
new Vue({
  data:{
         myValue:'x',
         myOtherValue:'y'
  },
  computed: {
       myComputed: myFunction(){
          return this['my' + 'Value']
       }
  }
})
```

As you can see the computed property will be cached and it is depended only on `data.myValue`. My question is how Vue.js caching system knows that run the computed function again only if `myValue` is changed?

If I change the `myOtherValue` variable, the `myComputed` function will use the cache, and will not be run again will I call it.

I thought about several ways how it is possible. But how Vuejs doing that?
I have read this article: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html and found no answer.

And what happen in this code, what it will be depeneded on?

```
const flag=2
new Vue({
  data:{
         myValue:'x',
         myOtherValue:'y'
  },
  computed: {
       myComputed: myFunction(){
          if (flag==1){
              return this['my' + 'Value']
          }
          else
              return this['my' + 'Other' + 'Value']
       }
  }
})
```

*Bonus:* I will appreciate I link to the relevant function in the VueJS code: https://github.com/vuejs/vue

Comment: You should read this : https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1_BlJxudppfKmAtfbNIcqNwzrC5vLrR_h1e09apcpdNY/edit#slide=id.p Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Thanks. I have read It. It is not explain about the caching system.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's the reactivity system of Vue.js, not a caching system.

The data in a component will be convert to getters and setters. When you access a value via a getter, the getter will add it to the dependencies, and when you modify the value via a setter, the setter will notify everyone who depends on the value.

Here is the source code, all the magic happens in this function: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/observer/index.js#L131

Comment: If this is the mechanism. It will be buggy. In the second example. If I change the `flag` value to `1`, I will get the caching answer when (flag==2), instead of new answer.

Comment: Yes, this is an interesting question. because `flag` is not reactive, so the `myComputed` will not aware about the change of `flag`. Here is the demonstration: http://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/rjOjjQ `flag` will be updated after 1 sec, but the computed property will not react to the flag

Comment: `myComputed` will only be updated after 10 secs, because you touch `myOtherValue`. If you change the interval to `this.myValue += 1`, `myComputed` will never be updated, because `myValue` is not a dependency of `myComputed`

Comment: So the correct way is to add `flag` to the data of that component, then it will be converted to a reactive property, and become a dependency of `myComputed`, then everything should work perfectly.

Comment: Here is another working example: http://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/vgNgQy in case you want to have a variable outside of the component. It must be an object, when you feed that object to the `data`, it will be converted to a reactive property, so `myComputed` can collect it as dependency correctly

Answer (score 48):

I will address only the specific question *how does vue.js know which dependencies affect which computed property?*

The simple answer is that each time vue evaluates a computed property it creates a map of all the reactive properties that were accessed in the span of that call. The next time any of these reactive properties change they will trigger a reevaluation of the computed property.

If during the most recent evaluation of a computed property, one of its reactive dependencies is never reached (maybe because it is within the non-traveled path of an if/else construct), subsequent changes to that reactive property will not trigger a reevaluation of the computed property.

Observe this behavior by modifying the two reactive properties in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lboyd3hf/4/) (by simply typing in their corresponding input boxes). A few things to note:

- the `called` computed property is evaluated once on document load (it's triggered because it's rendered in the template).
- because the `path` is set to `1` the reactive property that will be mapped as a dependency is `val1`. As a result it will be the only one that can trigger a reevaluation of `called` when it changes. The value of `val2` can also change but will not have the same effect on `called`, even though it's clearly present in the function.
- When you click on the "Change Path" button, `path` is toggled from `1` to `2`.
- right after the path switch, note that a change to `val1` will affect `called` only once more. Because `path` has been set to `2` prior to that last reevaluation, `val1` will not be reachable and will not be mapped as a dependency of `called` any longer. Subsequent changes to its value won't trigger a reevaluation of `called` from that point on. But then `val2` has now been mapped as a dependency of `called` and changes to it trigger the reevaluation the same way they did for `val1` earlier. It will be so until the next path toggle from `2` back to `1`.

Here's the code.

```
let path=1
let count=0
const vm=new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
         val1:null,
         val2:null,
  },
  computed: {
       called: function(){

            if (path==1){
              this.val1
            }
            if (path==2){
                this.val2
            }
            return "I was just called "+ ++count +" times"
       }
  },
  methods: {
    changePath(){
        path = path==2 ? 1 : 2
    }
  }
})
```

and corresponding template

```
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="val1"/> {{val1}}
  <br>
  <input v-model="val2"/> {{val2}}
  <br>
  <button @click="changePath">change path</button>
  <br>
  {{ called }}
</div>
```

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted answer. I appreciate CodinCat sharing a link to the original code but I'd prefer someone giving a gist of the way it works.

Comment: This clearly explain how the "wrong counting" happens. What's your suggestion on how to avoid it?

Comment: @Yiping Seems to me like the solution is to make sure computed functions always contain dependent properties at the top level. In the above example, `path` should not be in the global scope (outside of Vue's realm of responsibility) but should instead be in `data`, where setters and getters are utilized to monitor its state. If `data.path` changes, it will trigger a re-run of `called()` where it will then get see the change in `this.val2`. If `this.val2` were at the top level of the function (not inside the if) `called()` would have been executed if it changed.

Comment: @Yiping Essentially, if you want a computed function to register specific dependencies, you need to make sure that they're accessed every time the computed function is called. As a simple hack you could just list them at the beginning of the function. `this.val1; this.val2` at the top would make a change to either of them re-trigger the call to the computed function.

Comment: More explanation how it works [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20190523191010/http://skyronic.com:80/blog/vuejs-internals-computed-properties), pointed out by [this forum post](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-vuejs-knows-the-dependencies-of-computed-properties-for-caching/4945/6), which links to here.

Comment: @JoelMellon is there an alternative way to write the `this.val1; this.val2;` such that the functionality is the same but Code Scanners such as SonarQube won't [mark it as a bug](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/blob/master/javascript-checks/src/main/resources/org/sonar/l10n/javascript/rules/javascript/S905.html)?

Comment: @Wimateeka You could just assign variable(s), eg. `a = this.val1; a = this.val2; a = this.val3;` etc. There also may be a way to call the "magic" methods that accessing `this.val` actually calls, but I don't how that would be done off the top of my head. You might have to do something like `a = a;` depending on how strict your linter is, since `a` wouldn't have been used otherwise. You may also be able to add a comment to "skip" validating that line or two of code. You should add a comment regardless since this is pretty ridiculous overall, lol.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs it reads that:
Computed properties are cached, and only re-computed on reactive dependency changes.
However the following fiddle shows something a bit different.

1. https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/267/

From the fiddle if you set the flag to 2, the computed property will be re-evaluated and executed if you change `myOtherValue`, however this will not happen if the flag is set to 1. I think it keeps track of your if conditions.

In the docs usually you can find links to the relevant source code.
Here is the code for computed properties:

- https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=repo%3Avuejs%2Fvue+extension%3Ajs+%22computed%22&type=Code